# In select_tag, using options_from_collection_for_select , how to set selected element in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In select_tag, using  options_from_collection_for_select , how to set selected element in select box element in ruby on rails

```
 select_tag "server", options_from_collection_for_select(@server, "id", "name")
```

like selected="selected" set for an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `select_tag`, when you use `options_from_collection_for_select` use fourth parameter of `options_from_collection_for_select` that is **value(id in your example) to be selected**

```
<%= select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name",2)%>
```

In the above example, 2 is selected id, you can put id of which option you wish to select in select_tag

For more information ref link below

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Cheers!